# Realistic Barley Grains on a Potato Pc

Tags: texturing, materials, physics, rigid-body-simulation, photorealism

I just started on blender i am curantly trying to create a realistic beer/brewerie themed scene. I have already made a pretty good looking beer and now i want to create a bowl with the ingredients of said beer (Barley Grains and Hops) in the background. Ive tried creating the Barley with a rigid body sim to make it look realistic but my potato pc cant handle that and blender keeps crashing. Does anyone have a good idea on how i could achieve that with a different method? Scince im realy new to blender i dont realy know many technics yet. Also, any suggestions on making hops?
Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: it will be helpfull if you mention ur specs

Comment: TBH i dont know the exact specs. I do have 8gb of RAM, an I5 Core and some cheap-ish graphics card. VRam is quite low i think. Cycles in the viewport is a nightmare i can tell you that.